# Download large number of images using Axios/Node

Tags: node.js, axios, fs

I'm wanting to download a large number of images using Axios/Node.js

This is the code i'm using to download the images and then to save them to disk:

```
exports.DownloadImages = function (provider, data) {
    data.forEach(function (vehicle) {
        var images = vehicle.Gallery;
        images.forEach(function (image) {
            const url = transformation.replaceAll(image, '[size]', 'original');
            const filename = transformation.replaceAll(transformation.ImageFilename(url), '[size]', 'original');
            const writer = fs.createWriteStream('./export/' + provider + '/' + filename);
            api.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' }).then((response) => {
                response.data.pipe(writer);
            })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('[HELPER] DownloadImages ' + error + ' on Image ' + url);
                });

        });
    });
};
```

In my current test i'm downloading around 500 images, i would say that 80% of the images are downloaded correctly and saved, however i get a handful of errors in the log:

```
[HELPER] DownloadImages Error: read ECONNRESET on Image https:\\xxxx.com\imageurl.png
```

And when i view the images downloaded it seems like a number of them have only partially downloaded (i can see the top of the image but the rest is missing for example)

**EDIT:**

I've added the below to my axios get request which seems to help a little:

```
httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true })
```

But i get the following errors now:

```
Error: socket hang up
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out i was maxing my TCP connections.

Using this library i set a limit so it did it in batches with Axios and this has solved the problem for me

https://github.com/bernawil/axios-concurrency